# ParrotOS not saving my progress

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, parrot-os, persistence

The system boots up just fine. The problem is it does not save my work when I restart the system after powering off. It simply gives me a new desktop.

For more info:

- the OS: ParrotOS 5.2 security edition
- installed in Virtual Box 7.0

I don't know if it's a boot order or a storage issue. I would be glad if somebody could resolve it for me. Thanks in advance :)

I have attached certain pictures for reference. Kindly refer them if u need them.

[image: System settings]
[image: Storage VDI settings]
[image: Storage ISO settings]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veqQj.png)

Comment: After successfully installing you need to remove the installation ISO, as always.

Comment: removed the iso and unticked the optical boot loader but still does not work :( it cannot even save a normal text file just gives me a new desktop

Comment: A screenshot of the VM overview in VirtualBox would’ve been fine. // Please describe how you installed Parrot. Did you boot to the Live Desktop and then launch the installer, following its steps?

Comment: parrot os installed in virtual box via the install parrot launcher (same procedure as stated in the parrot os website for virtual box)

Comment: actually the system does not save the work even after u give "save" plus for exaple if i change the display setings in the system the system simply reverts them to the default

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be doing a Power Off if you want to continue from
where you were.

You should be putting the VM to Sleep.

(Side note: Files better be saved before, just in case.)

Comment: actually the system does not save the work even after u give "save" plus for example if i change the display setings in the system the system simply reverts them to the default .Would be glad if u are able to resolve this issue :)

Comment: Did you follow [this article](https://parrotsec.org/docs/virtualization/install-parrot-on-virtualbox/)?

Comment: precisely yes :)

Comment: Which display settings are these, in VirtualBox or ParrotOS ?

Comment: the display settings are in parrot os are not saving

Comment: to put in simple words for examle lets say i saved a file in parrot os. After reboot the system simply gives me a new desktop without storing the previous file (no storing of the data what i saved ) this is the issue i am facing at the moment . Even changes in the  disply setting in the system (parrot os) is not saved

Comment: Seems like the virtual disk has become read-only or is being rolled-back. I admit to being stumped. Perhaps you should recreate the VM, if something went wrong, paying extra attention to all messages.

Answer (score -2):

Issue resolved did a new install of parrot os :) thanks harrymc